# How to implement the standard Windows Phone 7 ComboBox replacement UI

Tags: combobox, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to implement what seems to be the standard UI replacement for comboboxes in Windows Phone 7. This is the TextBox + Navigate to New Page with Listbox approach you can see in the settings page of the Emulator.

I got the following issues while trying to implement this approach, speficically related to the TextBox:

1. If I use a ReadOnly TextBox the text appears in light gray, which is not really what I want. I want the normal black font there.
2. If I don't use a ReadOnly TextBox the virtual phone keyboard will appear in some rare situtations, even when I handled the MouseEnter event. I can't consistently reproduce the situations when the keyboard appears.

Which is the best approach to implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered just using a TextBlock with an invisible button over the top? Or associate a gesture to take the tap event?

You could also check out Alex's implementation here of a picker box.

[Implementing Picker Box functionality on WP7. - Alex Yakhnin's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/implementing-picker-box-functionality-on-wp7)

Answer (score 5):

The [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) has a `ListPicker` that is quite flexible and easy to use.